# how to add another layout below viewpager?

Tags: android

I am trying to add a linear layout below viewpager but unable to add.linear layout is not visible.

Layout below viewpager

[image]

Comment: The height of Linear Layout is wrap_content and has no child, so it won't be visible. Give height as 100dp and put some background color, it will be visible.

Comment: Thumb rule of SO -> Don't add code screenshot. Copy and paste the code.

Answer (score 0):

You have set fix height to ViewPager. than it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a fixed height to ViewPager

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/vpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/color_black">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_name"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="@color/blue">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It is not working,this layout is still not getting visible,

Answer (score -1):

Set linear layout height to constant or match_parent. So it will make the layout visible on layout editor.

Also, you need to add an attribute called `android:layout_below="@+id/Viewpg"` for the below linear layout. Which will force the linear layout to keep below the viewpager.